# equivalence norm of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If I prove a theorem based on $||.||_p$ for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ then can I interpret that this theorem is true on $||.||_q$ where $q \neq p$?

For example, I prove that $||A'||_2 \leq ||A||_2$
, so can I interpret that $||A'||_p \leq ||A||_p$ where $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $A'$ is the approximation of A based on SVD.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Do you have a specific result in mind?

Comment: For example, I prove that $||A'||_2 \leq ||A||_2$, so can I interpret that $||A'||_p \leq ||A||_p$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $A'$ is approximation of $A$ based on SVD.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to prove.

About the $p-$norms on a $n-$dimensional space $V$ (with $n < + \infty$), the main way to compare the different norms is that
$$\forall 1 \leq p \leq q, \quad \forall x \in V, \quad ||x||_q \leq ||x||_p \leq n^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}} ||x||_q$$

Comment: Assume $||A||_p \leq ||B||_p$ then $||A||_q \leq ||B||_q$ where $p,q \leq +\infty$. Is it true?

Comment: No, it has no reason to be true : for example, let's take $A=(0, 5) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $B=(4,4) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. You have $||A||_2 = 5 < \sqrt{32} = ||B||_2$, but $||A||_4 = 5 > \sqrt[4]{512} = ||B||_4$.

I think the only thing you can tell, assuming $||A||_p \leq ||B||_p$, is that there exists a constant $C$ such that $||A||_q \leq C ||B||_q$.